# access sql changing where parameters

Tags: sql, ms-access, where-clause

I have a problem with a DB I'm working on, I suspect is actually a very simple problem, still I can't solve it.
For sake of brevity I will use a very simplified case.
Let's say you have a table were have been stored data about expenses made by different persons, something like this:

```
IDPerson Expense data
1        2.00    1/1/14
1        1.00    1/2/14
1        1.00    1/3/14
2        1.00    1/1/14
2        1.00    1/2/14
3        1.00    1/3/14
```

What i need is a query that gives me, for each IDPerson, the totale of expenses made before or on 1/2/14 AND the total of the expenses unregarding the date, so

```
IDPerson TotalExpense ExpenseBefore1/2/14
1        4.00         2.00
2        2.00         2.00
3        1.00         0.00
```

It seems to me that to get this you shuld have different where clauses for each column(hence the title)

**What I tried:**

I tried to use two queries, one without where clause and one with

```
Where data<=1/2/14
```

then I used UNION to get the final result, technically it worked, but since this it is not really handy expecially because the real project is much more complicated than this and the final table has much more fields; is there any other way to obtain this?

P.S. You may have noticed that English is not my mothertongue, sorry for any error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT y.IDPerson,y.ExpensesTotal,isnull(x.ExpensesBefore_1_2_2014,0) as ExpensesBefore_1_2_2014  from 
(SELECT IDPerson ,sum(expenses) as ExpensesTotal from tableA GROUP BY IDPerson) as y full join ( SELECT  tableA.IDPerson , sum(expenses)  as    ExpensesBefore_1_2_2014 from tableA 
where data < '01.02.2014'
GROUP BY tableA.IDPerson ) as x on x.IDPerson = y.IDPerson
```

This query should work, also it should be preaty quick if the IDPerson is Indexed or PK.

I've updated the query, try this one.

SQL Fiddle : http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/fdaf0/1

Comment: sadly I didn't get this to work, in theory it should work, tough. There were just too many join to be made and the necessary query would be too messy.
Just in case somebody needs it: I just made different queries with different where clauses and then joined them appropriately, a much less elegant solution

Comment: You mean id doesn't work for the large amount of data of your database?